# How to pass in function a multidimensional char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

This is my code and it is not working.
It generate these errors when I pass char array like this `grid[r][c]`

```
[Error] use of parameter 'r' outside function body

[Error] use of parameter 'c' outside function body
```

It generate these errors when I pass char array like this `grid[][c]`

```
[Error] use of parameter 'c' outside function body
```

It generate these errors when I pass char array like this `grid[][]`

```
[Error] declaration of 'grid' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
```

And it runs perfectly fine when I pass this like this `grid[1][2]` i.e. just passing with an integer.0

I am stuck here and I don't know what to do or what not??

How to get rid of this problem?? Help Me !!!

Thanks in Advance!

```
void dfs(int r, int c, int pacman_r, int pacman_c, int food_r, int food_c, char grid[r][c]) {
    //logic here
}
int main(void) {
    int r, c;
    int pacman_r, pacman_c;
    int food_r, food_c;
    scanf( "%d %d", &pacman_r, &pacman_c);
    scanf( "%d %d", &food_r, &food_c);
    scanf( "%d %d", &r, &c);
    char grid[r][c];
    for( int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        scanf("%s[^\\n]%*c", grid[i]);
    }
    dfs( r, c, pacman_r, pacman_c, food_r, food_c, grid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's important to realize that you cannot actually pass an array to a function, regardless of what your function signature looks like.  Arrays will decay to pointers to their first element in this situation.

Comment: Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Is there any solution other than pointers??

Comment: @IskarJarak I am using Dev C++ 5.4

Comment: Sadly, there are no other solutions than pointers. Since an array is, in itself, nothing but a reference to the first member of the list.

Comment: @PlamZ But it is still not working

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: @IskarJarak same as before. No any effect after making it char** grid[][] or char* grid[][]

Comment: @MuhammadNouman PlamZ said as pass to `&grid[0][0]` and receive as `char *grid`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I did the same but it didn't work

Comment: it will work.(Should be treated as a `char *` instead of a 2D array.) also `scanf("%s[^\\n]%*c", grid[i]);` wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I treated it as char* but it is still not working

Comment: when `char grid[r][c];` pass by `&grid[0][0]` receive `char *grid`, `grid[r_index][c_index]` -> `grid[r_index * c + c_index]`, `grid[r_index]` -> `&grid[r_index * c]`

Comment: use C99 mode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOcjIPTGy3k for original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should pass the argument as a `char*` then work with it as a pointer to a flattened instance of your array

```
void fn(char* grid, int c){
    printf("%c", (grid+n*c)[m]);
}
```

this will print `grid[n][m]

Comment: sorry, forgot to pass it in, c is just the variable you're passing into your own function that corresponds to columns

Comment: But it is still not working. It didn't print anything. My dimensions of char array are r and c and I wrote it as (grid+r*c)[c]. Am I wrong or right??

Comment: you're wrong, you're accessing the element c adresses from the last address of your array which is uninitialized garbage.

Comment: So what should I do? Will you explain me??

Comment: replace the r in parens with the row you want to access. And the c in square brackets with the column you want to access. The c in parens should be total columns in your array.

Comment: I wrote it like this printf("%c", (grid+i*j)[c]). i = the no of row i want to access and j = the no of column i want to access and c = total no of columns. It still not working and print garbage.

Comment: you need to switch j and c

Comment: Ok Thanks Finally Worked :)

Comment: this code compiles

char grid[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
ber((char*)grid);
 int ber(char* berb){
  printf("%d", (berb+6)[2]);
}